# Permission denied or Host key problems

Tags: python, bash, apache, server, pyramid

I have a web application which is written with python (Pyramid) and in the apache server, inside of the one of the Python we are launching a SH file which is a service to sending SMS.
The problem is always the permission is denied.
we tried the run the SH file by login into the root and it works.
we changed the owner of the both files Python one and SH one to 'root' but not works!

any ideas?!

Comment: the code is a lot and I can not send it. is it necessary?

Answer (score 0):

```
ps aux | grep apache
```

Should show you the user apache is running as.

OR

You can see "User" and "Group" directives in httpd.conf.

Try changing the owner and group of your shell script file to the values set in conf

Answer (score 0):

Well you changed the owner of the files to root, and then you ran as `root`, and it worked, so that makes sense.  The problem is that `root` isn't necessarily the user executing the script in your webapp.  You need to find which user is trying to execute the script, and then change the files' ownership to that user (depending on how the scripts are invoked, you may need to `chmod` them as well to make sure they are executable)